# Send message to all people on my discord friend list via python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send a message to everybody on my friends list via python I want to do it without there id's is there a way to do this?

Comment: No one can see your friends so it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users' friend lists are not exposed to the public API. Even if they were, mass DM-ing users is against Discord's Terms of Service.